# What is a good way to learn Solidity?

Tags: solidity, react, mocha, chai

I’ve been watching YouTube videos and learning from Udemy on solidity for a year. I have basic understanding of blockchain. My problem is that although the instructors show the what to do and how to do, I don’t get the whys of implementation of their programming logic in general in learning solidity. I have learned Python, Java, JavaScript, and React. The authors have referred me to read the solidity, ethersjs, chai, mocha, and hardhat docs, but those docs often tell me the definitions of methods but I don’t get when and how to use them if I were to code on my own. I had to follow the instructor’s lectures and had to reason backward in learning how to program in Solidity, which is really hard. Any suggestions on good ways to learn solidity so learners know the what, how, when, and whys of the programming logic in Solidity, along with its testing frameworks and frontend? I will upvote multiple answers if the responses are helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solidity isn't really a hard language to learn if you know basic programming concepts.

There are multiple places that are teaching solidity and it is hard to say which is the best place.

So I will give you a bunch of resources so you can try it for yourself.

1. [Learn Blockchain, Solidity, and Full Stack Web3 Development with JavaScript – 32-Hour Course](https://youtu.be/gyMwXuJrbJQ)

Patrick Collins did a great job creating this course. There he will teach you solidity, ether.js, basics of blockchain, and multiple IDEs so you can pick the best that suits you.

2. [Cryptozombies](https://cryptozombies.io/en/course)

It is an interactive learning platform. It is good and precise. They will teach you multiple solidity concepts and web3.js while you are building a game.

3. [Chain Shot](https://www.chainshot.com/courses)
4. [Dapp University](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XLahq4qyors&ab_channel=DappUniversity)
   Dude does a great job teaching you multiple things. Although his videos are longer than usual, it is a good deal.
5. [Ethernaut](https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/)
   As you know, blockchain is a fairy new technology. So there are multiple hacks happening every month. So you must not ignore already happened attacks while writing a smart contract. And Ethernaut is the best place to learn solidity security while solving the challenges.
6. [A gold mine](https://www.useweb3.xyz/)
   This is gold mine. You can find links to multiple resources.

And there are couple github links I think you might find useful. But it is kind of big list so I will share my github profile and you can find them in starred [section](https://github.com/Ad-h0c?tab=stars).

With all said, I still believe the best resource is solidity docs. It is pure and you can find a lot of help there if you read them patiently.

Tell me if it helps!

Comment: Thanks Ad-h0c, I will try them out!

Comment: Do you mind if I ask how did you learn solidity?

Comment: I learned basic syntax then read standard solidity contracts after understanding what contract does. Then practicing until I understood all the topics I have learned.

Comment: I second this answer. By the time you get through the 32 hours of Patric Collins' course you will know literally everything you need to to get started on any project. From there, when you come across issues, google them or ask on a forum.